# Abort a procedure with flag, return, exception, goto or break

Tags: c++, exception, return, break, goto

I've got a code which parses a file and breaks up if invalid conditions are met.
The code is in C++ and goes like that:

```
bool ok = true;
if (task1() == false)
    ok = false;
if (ok && (task2() == false))
    ok = false;
if (ok && (task3() == false))
    ok = false;
cleanup();
return ok;
```

Now I'm looking into cleaner alternatives to get the same result.
As far as I see there are:

- using a flag and many conditions as in the code above

  - There are many redundant tests for the same information.
    The effect on the runtime will be negligible and probably
    entirely removed by the compiler but it still makes the code
    more complicated.
- you could wrap the tasks in a method and return from it

  - This looks much cleaner but you spread your code in multiple
    functions. Depending on your context there might be a long
    list of parameters. Further more many it is also not the
    best to spread returns all over the method.
- you could use exceptions

  - This will give some quite descriptive code but it is also
    heavy as you just want to skip some calls. Further more it
    might not be exactly an exceptional case.
- you could `break` from a `do while(0)` or another loop
  or switch statement.

  - Well, it is not really meant for such a task. Other than
    that you get a lightweight and compact implementation with
    and descriptive keyword.
- using a `goto` statement

  - That seems to combine most advantages. Still, I am unsure.
    Everywhere people are stating, that breaking multiple loops
    is the only remaining sensible use for this keyword.

I didn't find a discussion about such a code. Which implementations are generally suggested? Is this case mentioned in any C++ coding guidelines? Are there other practical options?

*Edit:* My goal does not seem to be clear. I'm looking for the best way how to break from a procedure and not for a way to call three methods. The described problem is more of an example. I'm interested in arguments for and against different syntaxes to do this.

In the code of object each method is a placeholder for a couple of code lines which are similar but differ from each other. There are maybe 50 code blocks. An old code block was looking like the following (I know that there are more things to optimize than just the objective of this question):

```
if (ok)
{
    keyString = "speed";
    tmpVal = configuration->getValue(section, keyString, -1);
    if (tmpVal != -1)
    {
        m_speed = tmpVal;
        if (m_speed < m_minSpeed)
            m_minSpeed = m_speed;
        m_needSpeed = true; 
    }
    else if (m_needSpeed)
    {
        ok = false;
        keyErr = keyString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use just `else if`?

Comment: *Everywhere people are stating, that breaking multiple loops is the only remaining sensible use for this keyword.* There's more than that, but `goto` should be one of the last tools you reach for because even if you get it right, no one's going to believe that you got it right. It is incredibly rare that you find a case where `goto` actually makes code simpler and easier to maintain, and when you find one, you're probably still wrong. Note: I wouldn't use `goto` for the multiple loop escape clause. I'd put the multiple loops in a function and return from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of these functions return a `bool`, it looks to me like the shown code is logically identical to:

```
bool ok= task1() && task2() && task3();

cleanup();

return ok;
```